# Qt position of item in scene at different scales

Tags: qt, linear-algebra

This question is regarding Qt's GraphicsViewFramework.

I have two QGraphicsItems of the same type, A and B seen here. I have set both objects to ignore parent transformation,

[image: normal zoom]

B is a child of A, so when I move A so does B. and as you see in the picture the position of B is (-300, -300) because that value is relative to it's parent position. But the scenePosition is displaying correctly to (0,0) as expected.

When I zoom in the scene, things get weird. Since B is a child of A, it exists in A's coordinate system so it will maintain it's position relative to A. see picture.

[image: zoomed in]

As you can see the position of B in the view seems shifted. I wan't to find the relative position of B in the current zoom level. How can I achieve this?

Comment: this seems to be a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459318/maintaining-relative-child-position-after-applying-qgraphicsitemitemignorestra

Comment: Thanks I saw that before posting, but this is different.

Comment: Then maybe you would add some code? I tried to reproduce this scene but it was ok, no shifts

Comment: When you created B, did you set A to be it's parent?

Comment: Yes, with setParentItem